Why does my object look different in the edit viewport vs. the object/sculpt viewport?
I've been sculpting this character for a class, and was trying to find a way to reduce the number of faces because my Blender had been running extremely slow anytime I tried to edit or sculpt this object further.
I applied a decimate modifier, but noticed the changes only showed up in object or sculpt mode, so the faces were not actually reduced. Then, I tried to reduce the voxel size under remesh in the object data properties, and that instantly ruined it, but once again, changes don't show in the edit mode.
I would like to know why changes aren't showing up in edit mode, how I can fix the remesh mistake I made, and also how to actually reduce the number of faces in the workspace so my blender will stop smoother. Any help would be so appreciated! Thank you!



Do you have a decimate modifier on your object? That modifier won't show in Edit mode, generally.
